# Error installing sqlite3 gem rvm opensuse premission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, sqlite, rvm, opensuse

new to linux. Installing Ruby 2.0 and rails 4.0 through rvm. Got it working on my laptop with linux ubuntu but having problem on my work computer with linux openSUSE.

Installed rvm, ruby and rails. Created a rails app but when i run bundle install I get this:

```
**Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /home/alf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/API_CHANGES.rdoc
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.**
```

Also got this when running bundle install:

```
**Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /home/alf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/alf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
        --enable-local
        --disable-local
Gem files will remain installed in /home/alf/.bundler/tmp/10121/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/alf/.bundler/tmp/10121/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.**
```

I have sqlite3 installed, but don#t know if its installed locally somewhere. I'm new to linux and openSUSE. Please help me.

When I run gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'  I get:

```
**ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /home/alf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/API_CHANGES.rdoc**
```

This drives me crazy, google but cant find a solution that works.

Comment: sqlite3.h is missing. Try `'port install sqlite3 +universal'` you do not have sqlite3 and its necessary libraries... then start gem installation thanks

Comment: Then I get this: If 'port' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf port

Comment: `yum install ruby-devel sqlite sqlite-devel ruby-rdoc`  please do this

Comment: Don#t work eather, how do i install "yum" and "port"? If 'yum' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf yum

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: Linux OpenSuse latest version

Comment: do you have sqlite3 installed in your linux

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on Ubuntu, trying to start a new Rails project. In this case `sqlite3.h is missing`, means that *libsqlite3-dev* is missing, I guess (I'm new with Ubuntu and Sqlite3).  The answer can be found right here : [Installing sqlite headers](http://www.databasically.com/2010/03/05/installing-sqlite-headers-on-ubuntu-sqlite3-h-not-found/).

```
~$ sudo apt-get install sqlite3
~$ sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
~$ bundle install
```

After that, `rails server` worked well for me. I had my *Welcome aboard* in localhost.